# Prolog graph acyclic

Tags: prolog, directed-acyclic-graphs, transitive-closure

I am trying to write a predicate that writes out all the ways from one node to another in a acyclic graph. If I example have these nodes/edges.

```
node(x,y).
node(x,z).
node(y,z).
```

And then I have tried something like:

```
predicate(X,Y):-
    node(X,Y),
    ...
```

but somehow I need to do this recursively which I need help with. Anyone got any ideas? Thanks

Comment: There are lots of posts regarding graphs in Prolog on Stackoverflow. You should try doing a search "[prolog] acyclic graphs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work well in this maybe. (But I'm not so familiar with Prolog.)

```
route(X, Z, [])    :-  node(X, Z).
route(X, Z, [Y|T]) :-  node(X, Y), route(Y, Z, T).
```

and then

```
?- findall(E, route(x, z, E), Routes).
% ==> Routes = [[], [y]].
```

**+ EDIT**

```
print_all_routes(X, Y) :- findall(E, (route(X, Y, E), write(E), nl), _).
```

Comment: Seems to work but I am interested in writing out the paths inside the program. So all you would've to enter is start = X and end = Y.

Comment: It is nice to rewrite the query to such a predicate. I've edit my answer.